# Getting facebook Events list Using ios sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am new to ios development. I want to integrate facebook for my ipad app and then i want to get the list of events. how do i get the events list.

Thanks in advance.
Raja

Answer (score -1):

You'll probably want to [start here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/). It details the Facebook SDK for iOS and has a reasonable amount of sample code to get you started.